# JQuery equivalent to Ruby's a || b

Tags: javascript, ruby

In Ruby, I can write `a || b` and the function will choose a if it exists, and if not, b.

How can I do this in JQuery without writing something grossly cumbersome like:

```
if (a){
  a
} else {
  b
}
```

Also, does JQuery have an equivalent to Ruby's `a ||= b`?

Comment: `a = a || b;` should work.  Are you having issues?

Comment: jQuery doesn't have operators, JavaScript OTOH does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery is just a JavaScript library  and in JavaScript we have the same.

```
var c = a || b;
```

This is because

> If the first object is *truthy*, that gets returned. Otherwise, the second object gets returned.

Answer (score 6):

In JavaScript, `a || b` evaluates to the first *truthy* value (or the last value if both are *falsy*), just as in Ruby. (Remember, jQuery is just a *library* for JavaScript.)

*However*, JavaScript has many more *falsy* (*non-truthy* values) than Ruby does so care may need to be taken. See [Truthy and Falsy: When All is Not Equal in JavaScript](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/).

For instance, in JavaScript: `"" || "foo"` will result in `"foo"` although it would have evaluated to `""` in Ruby.

Happy coding.

---

And yes, JavaScript supports `x Q= y` for all binary operators `x = x Q y`. An easy way to find out is to just Try It And See :)

Answer (score 4):

```
var myVariable = myVariable || "Default";
```